# A cert which was removed from Keychain Access persists for Chrome, Firefox

Tags: macos, certificate, keychain

I installed a self-signed certificate for my local dev environment, running off of docker. One of my company's prod sites tried to use the cert, even though the domains are completely different (`https://localhost` vs `https://defintely-not-localhost.company-name.com`).

Then, I opened Keychain Access, unlocked it, right clicked on the localhost cert and deleted. After locking Keychain Access and restarting Chrome, the site still tries to use the self-signed cert. I've tried uninstalling Chrome, but I don't think this is a Chrome issue, as I can reproduce it in FireFox.

Yes, I tried turning it off and on again. I verified the offending cert is no longer in Keychain Access too.

Any ideas?